# How to Hide Toolbar and assign Option menu and Searchview to TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to Hide my Toolbar from my App and show Option menu and searchView to Tablayout.

Standard View
[image]

Required
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no solution out of the box. But in Android you can do almost everything, but by your own hand or by searching some third-party library.

For example:

- Create FrameLayout with 2 childs (one child is Linear layout with tabs and buttons, other child is search view, you can try to play with standart SearchView or create your own or use [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView))
- Create LinearLayout with childs TabLayout and 2 ImageViews (one for search, one for menu).
- Then you need to add ripple effect to both ImageViews and provide icons for each (you can find them in [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/))
- Then you need to provide apearing [Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) with our options menu
- Then you need to provide click on search button and animation of fading tabs and appearing search view (just hide first child of frame layout and show second).

I know, that is can seems strange. But when you want something not ordinary, often you need to make a lot of things by yourself (or search for some libraries)

**Also**, you can try to use a small hack as more quick solution. Suppose you need 112 dp for both icons (search, overflow), then you can make:

- FrameLayout with 2 childs: first child is Toolbar with width match_parent and no title, no back or burger icon, only menu; second child TabLayout with width match_parent - 112dp
- Thus, you will have touchable area for tablayout, except small area in the right, there you can have touchable area for menu

So for user all will be seemed like on your screenshot, and you will need to use more less code, than for the first variant

Comment: Not at all but using custom view it is possible :)